# Promisify of Express middleware

Tags: node.js, express, promise, node-promisify

How to promisify function what is `Express middleware` (for example `authenticate(arg1, arg2)(req, res, next)`)?

I tried promisify method from `util` and also from `es6-promisify` but none of those work. I am getting error:

`TypeError: authenticate(...) is not a function`

when I do:

`const authenticate = promisify(passport.authenticate);`

(`passport.authenticate`) is the middleware.

**My actual problem is:**
I am using `passport-jwt` module for `passport` and I want to reuse `passport.authenticate` middleware as normal `isLoggedIn` function. I do not want to make same function to check JWT when there is this function. Also I do not want to promisify this middleware manually because I will be doing it in many places and its code repetition.

Comment: You will have to show people what you're actually trying to accomplish (the end goal, not just this step in the process).  Middleware is a special type of function.  With Express 4, you would not return a promise from middleware - that's not how  Express works.  It sounds like you're trying to solve some problem the wrong way so we need to see the higher level problem.

Comment: @jfriend00 thx, I added actual problem

Comment: Well, middleware works differently than a plain `isLoggedIn()` function would work.  Usually, your middleware would set something in the session and `isLoggedIn()`would check the current user's session to see if they are logged in.  Completely different functions that work differently and do different things.  You can  probably factor out some common code and have each function share some code, but a middleware function is a special type of function you would not use directly in some other context.

Comment: Ohh, and middleware does not have the right kind of function signature or style of working to promisify it automatically either.  You may need to break out a common component, you can promisify and share.